# Array index inside vectorization

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

Is there a way to utilize the array indices within a vectorized numpy equation?

Specifically, I have this looping code that sets each value of a 2d array to the distance to some arbitrary center point.

```
img=np.ndarray((size[0],size[1]))
for x in range(size[0]):
    for y in range(size[1]):
        img[x,y]=math.sqrt((x-center[0])**2+(y-center[1])**2)
```

How might I vectorize that?

Comment: I think the term you are looking for is "vectorization", not "linearization"

Comment: @NilsWerner good point.  Question rephrased.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this easily using broadcasting:

```
import numpy as np

size = (64, 64)
center = (32, 32)

x = np.arange(size[0])
y = np.arange(size[1])

img = np.sqrt((x - center[0]) ** 2 + (y[:, None] - center[1]) ** 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some help from Pandas would make this task relatively easy:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# get all of the xy pairs
xys = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(range(size[0]), range(size[1]))))

# calculate distance
xys["distance"] = np.sqrt((xys[0] - center[0]) ** 2 + (xys[1] - center[1]) ** 2)

# transform to a 2d array
img = xys.set_index([0, 1])["distance"].unstack()

# if you want just the Numpy array, not a Pandas DataFrame
img.values
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

```
import numpy as np

size = (6, 4)
center = (3, 2)
img_xy = np.array([[(x, y) for x in range(size[0])] for y in range(size[1])])

img = np.sum((img_xy - center) ** 2, axis=2) ** 0.5
print('\nPlan1:\n', img)

img = np.linalg.norm(img_xy - center, axis=2)
print('\nPlan2:\n', img)
```

You will get this:

```
Plan1:
 [[3.60555128 2.82842712 2.23606798 2.         2.23606798 2.82842712]
 [3.16227766 2.23606798 1.41421356 1.         1.41421356 2.23606798]
 [3.         2.         1.         0.         1.         2.        ]
 [3.16227766 2.23606798 1.41421356 1.         1.41421356 2.23606798]]

Plan2:
 [[3.60555128 2.82842712 2.23606798 2.         2.23606798 2.82842712]
 [3.16227766 2.23606798 1.41421356 1.         1.41421356 2.23606798]
 [3.         2.         1.         0.         1.         2.        ]
 [3.16227766 2.23606798 1.41421356 1.         1.41421356 2.23606798]]
```

If you have any question, you could ask me.